# Hive - connection to Java via JDBC

Tags: java, database, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have a problem. I can't connect my simple java application to my db. I think it's a problem with drivers.

Here are hive logs, when I'm starting it:
[image]
My simple code:

```
package bazahive;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class baza{
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
              Class.forName(driverName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.exit(1);
            }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:50070/przychodnia", "", "");
        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Wybierz");
        System.out.println("0 aby dodać do istniejącej tabeli wiersz");
        System.out.println("1 aby usunąć z istniejącej tabeli wiersz");
        String x = odczyt.nextLine();
        switch(x){
            case("0"):
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                String SQL = "SELECT ai(),* FROM pacjenci";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                while (rs.next()){
                    int ai = rs.getInt("ai()");
                    String imie = rs.getString("imie");
                    String p = ai + " " + imie;
                    System.out.println(p);

        }

    }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:50070/przychodnia: Invalid status 72
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:219)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:157)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at bazahive.baza.main(baza.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status 72
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:307)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:195)
    ... 5 more
```

I added two jars into my project:

```
hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar
hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar
```

I'm using derby from java.

EDIT:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1158)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:960)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:957)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:624)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.<init>(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.getHttpClient(HiveConnection.java:402)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createHttpTransport(HiveConnection.java:250)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:193)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:157)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at hive.main(hive.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1020)
    ... 15 more
```

EDIT2:
[image]

Translating: There was a connection refused because they not found the database.

Comment: Your URL is incorrect.  Cutting & pasting the message into Google would have told you that: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/23864/hive-http-transport-mode-problem.html

Comment: I still have a lot of problems...

Comment: Clearly.  Did you fix the URL?

Comment: Hard to diagnose because Log4j2 is not configured correctly. Best fix that first. Add log4j-api-2.7, log4j-core-2.7, log4j-jcl-2.7 to the start of the classpath. Ensure a valid log4j2.xml configuration file is in the classpath. This should give better error reports pointing to the actual problem.

Comment: If the edit made the URL error go away, I'd recommend that you remove it from your question.  It's misleading to keep if it doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: Ok i did something else, i hive-site.xml and i found a problem. I used hive and bad localhost. I should use derby. Now connection almost running, but does not search my database. I'm adding a photo to the main post.